# What does exporting an Android application do, exactly?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, release, apk

The instructions at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html indicate that I should export my android application before releasing it to the public. What are the steps that are performed in the export?

Here's what I know about:

1. android:debuggable in <Application> is set to false in the AndroidManifest.xml
2. The APK is signed by the developer's (my) key, rather than the built-in debug key
3. zipalign is run on that signed APK

   I set android:debuggable to false manually in my AndroidManifest.xml, and compared a debug and exported apk. These are the only files that were different:

   `Binary files ../../release/x//classes.dex and x/classes.dex differ`
   `Binary files ../../release/x//META-INF/CERT.RSA and x/META-INF/CERT.RSA differ`
   `diff -r ../../release/x//META-INF/CERT.SF x/META-INF/CERT.SF`
   `diff -r ../../release/x//META-INF/MANIFEST.MF x/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

   So does my list above include everything? Or does the different classes.dex indicate that there is some other difference between a debug and exported apk?

   Thanks to Error 454's answer below, I ran baksmali on the classes.dex file in each apk, and I found one difference:

   `diff -r out/xx/xx/xx/BuildConfig.smali ../../../release/x/out//xx/xx/xx/BuildConfig.smali`
   `7c7`
   `< .field public static final DEBUG:Z = true`
   `---`
   `> .field public static final DEBUG:Z`

   So I suppose I could add a fourth item to this list:
4. In class BuildConfig (gen/.../BuildConfig.java), DEBUG is set to false.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what you've listed, proguard is also ran during export.

If you are incredibly curious about the nature of the difference in classes.dex, you can grab [baksmali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/downloads/list), unzip your apk and decompile the classes.dex file:

```
java -jar baksmali-1.3.3.jar classes.dex
```

This will create an out/ folder with the contents that you can then diff between old/new.

The reason the BuildConfig.DEBUG flag is different is because of you exporting a Release version vs a Debug version as explained in the [SDK Release Notes Revision 17](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html):

> Added a feature that allows you to run some code only in debug mode.
>   Builds now generate a class called BuildConfig containing a DEBUG
>   constant that is automatically set according to your build type. You
>   can check the (BuildConfig.DEBUG) constant in your code to run
>   debug-only functions.

Comment: Thanks. I ran baksmali and amended my question.

Comment: BuildConfig was added in SDK Revision 17 http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps that occur for a build, whether the target is `debug` or `release`. This isn't a direct answer but I would suggest looking at `android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml`

Once you have the file open, do a search for `target name="release"`. You'll see the `depends` attribute which lists other targets in the same file that will be called. You can compare the targets a `release` runs compared to the `debug` target. Inside of each target, you can see specifically what gets run (such as some of the utilities in `android-sdk/platform-tools`), along with what determines if something gets run.

You can also see what parameters get passed to external utilities during a target call which allows you to read the documentation on those parameters of the utility to see specifically what is occurring for a particular step.

And to note, while you might be exporting the application in eclipse, investigating the ant build.xml provides a way to systematically identifying every step that will be performed for a full build.

As an example for how complex this might get, if you look at the target `-set-release-mode`, you can see an instance where one can generate a debug package signed with the release keys instead of the debug key.

Answer (score 0):

> Or does the different classes.dex indicate that there is some other
>   difference between a debug and exported apk?

Even with identical code, the resulting classes.dex doesn't have to be binary identical with previously compiled versions. That's due to different ways the compiler optimizes the code AFAIK.